# Does Power Set of an Open Set include only Open Subsets?

Tags: general-topology, definition

I was studying introductory topology, got stuck on this conceptual problem.
We define Power set as the collection of all possible subsets of a set, which means that it could include both open and closed subsets.
Hence when we define a trivial topology as the Power Set of X, how can we prove that it is closed with respect to arbitrary union and finite intersection??

Comment: Closed with respect to arbitrary union and finite intersection means an arbitrary union and finite intersection is in the topology; that’s different from closed meaning complement is open

Comment: Thanks, I guess I got confused.

Comment: By the way, I think you are talking about the *discrete* topology.  In the [trivial topology](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_topology), only the empty set and the whole set are open

Answer (score 1):

You are misleading yourself by talking about open and closed sets from some other topology than the trivial one you mention.  This trivial topology you talk about is more usually known as the discrete topology.  (The usual trivial topology has only the empty set and the whole space open.)  In it, every subset is open and closed.  If your base set is $\Bbb R$, for example, there is nothing special about $(0,1)$ or $[2,3]$, they are both open and both closed.  The open sets are closed under arbitrary unions and intersections because every union and intersection is one of the subsets of your space..

Comment: What is your definition of open sets? Is it different from what we read in elementary analysis? My definition says "A set is said to be open if for every point in it, we can find atleast one neighbourhood which lies completely inside the set". According to that $[2,3]$ is not a open set in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @NIHIRAGARWAL:  That is the usual topology on the reals, which we use most often.  A topology is defined as a collection of subsets of the universe that are open including the empty set and the universe where the collection is closed under finite intersection and arbitrary unions.  Closed sets are complements of open ones.  The discrete topology just says that all subsets of the universe are open.  As an arbitrary union of subsets is a subset and any finite intersection of subsets is a subset, this is a topology.  It is the one referenced in your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I understood now.